# Cookie ist null, but has a value in the browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I am trying to set a cookie which stores the current TimezoneOffset.

```
         window.onload = function () {

         var timezone_cookie = "timezoneoffset";

         if (!$.cookie(timezone_cookie)) { // if the timezone cookie not exists create one.

             // check if the browser supports cookie
             var test_cookie = 'test cookie';
             $.cookie(test_cookie, true);

             if ($.cookie(test_cookie)) { // browser supports cookie

                 // delete the test cookie.
                 $.cookie(test_cookie, null);

                 // create a new cookie 
                 $.cookie(timezone_cookie, new Date().getTimezoneOffset());

                 location.reload(); // re-load the page
             }
         }
         else { // if the current timezone and the one stored in cookie are different then
             // store the new timezone in the cookie and refresh the page.

             var storedOffset = parseInt($.cookie(timezone_cookie));
             var currentOffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();

             if (storedOffset !== currentOffset) { // user may have changed the timezone
                 $.cookie(timezone_cookie, new Date().getTimezoneOffset());
                 location.reload();
             }
         }
     };
```

But when I try to read the value later, the debugging Tool in Visual Studio tells me, it is "null".

If I load the page and inspect the cookies, a value (-120) is set.
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

The javascript is within the _Layout.cshtml file. The code I want to execute with the cookie looks like this:

```
var timeOffSet = HttpContext.Current.Session["timezoneoffset"];  // read the value from session

        if (timeOffSet != null)
        {
            var offset = int.Parse(timeOffSet.ToString());
            dt = dt.AddMinutes(-1 * offset);

            return dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
        }

        // if there is no offset in session return the datetime in server timezone
        return dt.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
```

Function is called from a View, so the js code should have been executed by this time.

Comment: cookie it is not session, just Request.Cookies["timezoneoffset"] instead of HttpContext.Current.Session["timezoneoffset"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you try to get the value in a wrong way - the cookies are not stored in session variable.

You can use this line instead:

```
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["timezoneoffset"];
if ((cookie != null) && (cookie.Value != ""))
{
    var offset = int.Parse(cookie.Value.ToString());
    dt = dt.AddMinutes(-1 * offset);
    return dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
}
return dt.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
```